# Loop in PL/SQL (Brewbean's Database)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

(First time posting) and having some trouble with a simple loop statement in Oracle 10g using the Brewbean Database. I have no idea what I am doing wrong with this, I have tried multiple times to change the select statement to the primary key of the second table (bb_shopper) and oracle is still returning the same error. I do not understand this.

The Question this comes from: Create a loop that will determine the number of items that can be purchased based on the price of the item and the total available amount to spend, use one initialized variable to represent the price amount and another to represent the total available to spend.

My Answer:

```
SQL> /* 2-6 Loop */
SQL> 
SQL> declare
  2          v_idshopper bb_basket.idshopper%type;
  3          v_price bb_product.price%type;
  4          v_stock bb_product.stock%type;
  5          v_firstname   bb_shopper.firstname%type;
  6          v_lastname    bb_shopper.lastname%type;
  7          v_idproduct bb_product.idproduct%type;
  8  begin
  9          select  price, stock, firstname, lastname
 10          into v_price, v_stock, v_firstname, v_lastname
 11          from bb_product join bb_shopper using (idproduct)
 12          where v_idproduct like idproduct
 13          group by firstname, lastname;
 14  
 15          for i in 21..27 LOOP
 16              dbms_output.put_line('Customer is ' ||v_idshopper ||' ' ||v_firstname ||' ' ||v_lastname);
 17              dbms_output.put_line('The total number of items that can be purchased is '||v_stock);
 18              dbms_output.put_line('The total amount that would be spend is '||v_price);
 19          end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
    from bb_product join bb_shopper using (idproduct)
                                           *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 41: 
PLS-00302: component 'IDPRODUCT' must be declared 
ORA-06550: line 11, column 41: 
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "BB_SHOPPER"."IDPRODUCT": invalid identifier 
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2: 
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Not too sure if I should post the tables I am pulling this data from? Let me know if I should and I will gladly post them.

Edit: Tables used in Question above...

```
TABLE bb_shopper (
    idShopper number(4),
    FirstName varchar2(15),
    LastName varchar2(20),
    Address varchar2(40),
    City varchar2(20),
    State char(2),
    ZipCode varchar2(15),
    Phone varchar2(10),
    Fax varchar2(10),
    Email varchar2(25),
    UserName varchar2(8),
    Password varchar2(8),
    Cookie number(4) DEFAULT 0,
    dtEntered date DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    Promo char(1),
        CONSTRAINT shopper_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idShopper)
    );

TABLE bb_product (
    idProduct number(2) ,
    ProductName varchar2(25) ,
    Description varchar2(100) ,
    ProductImage varchar2(25),
    Price number(6,2),
    Active number(1),
    Type char(1),
    stock number(5,1),
    ordered number(3),
    reorder number(3),
    idDepartment number(2),
        CONSTRAINT prod_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idProduct)
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error message is pretty clear - your table `IDSHOPPER` doesn't contain an `IDPRODUCT` column. Please add the DDL statements for all tables involved to your question (not as a comment, but by editing the question).

Comment: Also, your loop doesn't make much sense - you're printing the same values seven times in a row. And where do the hard-coded 21 / 27 come from?

Comment: You are using "USING" keyword this implicitly means that in both tables that you are joining("bb_product" and "bb_shopper") there has to be identically named column "idproduct".Please check if this is the case, if it is not the case then join differently named columns using "ON condition" syntax.

Comment: Thank you Frank I added the tables. I am using the 21-27 comes from the idshopper column (only id's 21-27)

Comment: That would make more sense that there are no corresponding idproduct or idshopper columns on both tables. Thanks ivanzg!